# Why isn't this image changing function working?

Tags: javascript, html, image

Here is what I wrote:

```
var img_current = 0;
var image0 = new Image()
image0.src = "img/image_centrale/1_house_0.jpg"
var image1 = new Image()
image1.src = "img/image_centrale/1_house_1.jpg"
var image2 = new Image()
image2.src = "img/image_centrale/1_house_2.jpg"

function affich_centrale()
{
    if (house_bought == 1 && neighborhood_bought == 0)
    {
        img_current = 1;
        document.images.main.src = eval("image" + img_current + ".src").innerHTML = 'image_centrale';
    }
    else if (house_bought == 2 && neighborhood_bought == 0)
    {
        img_current = 2;
        document.images.main.src = eval("image" + img_current + ".src").innerHTML = 'image_centrale';
    }
    else{}
```

This will go on, but I think you get the gist. What's wrong with my code? The images won't change as my "house_bought" variable changes.

In my HTML part, I simply put this:

```
<div id="image_centrale">
    <img src="img/image_centrale/1_house_0.jpg"  name="main" />
</div>
```

Note: This is an upcoming full html/js game website.

Comment: ...`eval`? That kills kittens and puppies, you know. But to answer your question, `someImgElm.src` will be a _String_, and there is no _innerHTML_ on a _String_. On top of that, you're using `=` twice, so it's like you're trying to set the _LHS_ and the _centre_ parts to the _RHS_ (`'image_centrale'`). ..Furthermore, I don't see where `house_bought` and `neighborhood_bought` are being set, so you may always end up in your `else {}` anyway.

Comment: I'm sorry I should've been more precise, house_bought and 'hood are both set before. But as I've tested it (with an alert button warning me of variable changes) the function "kind of" work, because it tells me that "img_current = 1" and also 2 when the conditions are met.
So, I'm guessing it's the document.images(...) part who's not working properly (I must have written it wrong)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you use `src` and `innerHTML` at the same time? `src` is all you need, and there is no need for `eval` as well. Try this:

```
<div id="image_centrale">
    <img src="" name="main" />
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var img_current = 0;
    var house_bought = 1;
    var neighborhood_bought = 0;
    var image0 = new Image()
    image0.src = "img/image_centrale/1_house_0.jpg"
    var image1 = new Image()
    image1.src = "img/image_centrale/1_house_1.jpg"
    var image2 = new Image()
    image2.src = "img/image_centrale/1_house_2.jpg"

    function affich_centrale() {
        if (house_bought == 1 && neighborhood_bought == 0) {
            img_current = 1;
            document.images.main.src = image0.src;
        }
        else if (house_bought == 2 && neighborhood_bought == 0) {
            img_current = 2;
            document.images.main.src = image1.src;
        }
        else { }
    }
    affich_centrale();
</script>
```

In this code example, I hard-coded the values for the variables just to make it a working example, so you will always see the first image. Change it to suite your needs.

Comment: What you suggested made a lot more sense actually, but it still only shows the image set in the html at first. Is the code in the "div" not suitable for the function?

Comment: Of course it will show it. If you want to start with empty image place holder, then try `<div id="image_centrale"><img src="" name="main" /></div>`. I will update my answer.

Comment: On Chrome, it still doesn't show anything as the 'house_bought' variable changes, but on Firefox, it displays the little icon that tells there's no image to be found! Could the problem come from the CSS?

Comment: Well, I don't know the values of your variables and I don't know how you are calling your function. I will updated update my answer to include full code with hard-coded values for the variables. You see it working and them modify it to suit your needs.

Comment: That's really simple, I just have a button, when clicked activates another function and incrementes house_bought each click.
However, I think you covered enough so I can get it working on my own. Thanks a lot my friend!
However one final question, if I want to start with an image, is it okay to write it: `<img src="image0.src" name="main" />` or must I write the full path?

Comment: You have to write the full path. `image0.src` is only accessible in JavaScript, so you can put it there if you want. Just add another line `document.images.main.src = image0.src;` instead of the line `affich_centrale();` in my example.